# How to make a animation to an alert?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use JS to show an alert and make it automatically disappear.
However, I want to it disappears gradually. How to add animation to it?
I also want to the alert always in the center of the window.

```js
socket.on('message', function (dataContent) {
  
  $( document ).ready(function() { $('#myModal').modal('show'); });


    setTimeout(showAlert(1), 3000);

});

function showAlert(hideAfter) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    if(hideAfter) {
        setTimeout(fadeItOut, 5000);
    }
}

function fadeItOut() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Your "alert" message here.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"-->
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Something like `el.fadeOut()`...

Comment: @RayonDabre, `el` is a DOM element, it does not have a `fadeOut` method, you are thinking of a jQuery wrapped element

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I am aware of that.. That was just a pointer mate!

Comment: I tried el.fadeOut(), but it can not define the time? I can only use the el.fadeOut("slow")?

Comment: @LuyaoWang, `el` has to be `jQuery-wrapped-object` as `DOMElement` does not have method `fadeOut`

Comment: @RayonDabre. I tried el.fadeOut(), but it can not define the time? It looks like I only use the el.fadeOut("slow") to let it slow down.

Comment: You could roll your own animation code, and there's plenty of information online about how to do that, but the best thing to do is find a JavaScript library that already does animations (I like snabbt.js) and use that.

Comment: Just create a hidden and visible class, and do it with css3 transitions, why are we over complicating things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function showAlert(hideAfter) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
  if(hideAfter) {
    setTimeout(fadeItOut, 5000);
  }
}

function fadeItOut() {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
}

// Jquery has loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(showAlert(1), 3000);
});
```

```css
 .fade {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2.25s linear !important;
      -moz-transition: opacity 2.25s linear !important;
       -ms-transition: opacity 2.25s linear !important;
        -o-transition: opacity 2.25s linear !important;
           transition: opacity 2.25s linear !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Your "alert" message here.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have you considered using a bootstrap modal instead?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You could style it much better than an alert box and also set a timeout function to allow it to fade out. Do you have the option to use jquery and bootstrap? If so, I would be glad to throw together a simple demo for you.

Edited to show initial functionality you requested. Let me know if you'd like to change from here and I will be happy to assist.

Basically, as soon as jquery is loaded I've set a timeout function that will trigger your alert and then another timeout function to hide it after a few seconds. You can also trigger the modal by clicking the button.

You can call showAlert(0) to show the modal and not have it close automatically. Likewise, you can call fadeItOut() to hide it whenever you want.

Comment: jQuery and bootstrap are okay to me! Thank you so much! Also, is it possible to separate "showing the alert" and "fade it out" into two functions? Maybe in further step, I would like to show the alert when receive the signal A and when the browser receive the signal B, the alert would be faded out. Thank you again.

Comment: Absolutely, will post that shortly.

Comment: Updated post to show demo. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. The question is if I do not want to use the "button", how to call this function? It turned to be an error - " $(...).modal is not a function". I added the "#myModal"div and use setTimeout(showAlert(1), 3000) as well as the rest two functions.

Comment: Did you include jQuery and bootstrap as I did?  That button is just there for convenience, it's not needed. Calling showAlert(1) is what triggers it to open. Can you post your current HTML and JavaScript?  You can't just have a div with ID of myModal. It needs to follow the modal template I posted used by bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Weber, I edited my question and posted my current code.

Comment: Luyao, that code is not working because "socket" is not defined in this context. If you place this before your socket.on function it will show up. Also, you are including jquery twice so get rid of one of those:     $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
});

Comment: Weber, I added "$( document ).ready(function() { $('#myModal').modal('show'); });" before socket.on function. But it still exist the error - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept this as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: by the way, I do not want to fade the screen. I just want to show the alert. How to do that?

Comment: The css .fade class rules dictate the fade in the example I provided. You can just get rid of that css if you don't want it to fade in and out.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it by adding ".modal-backdrop {background: none;}"

Comment: Ah, apologies. You were referring to the grayed out background. Yes, that's the right thing to do. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 animation. For example in Chrome, define CSS like:

```
#success-alert {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```